# Satisfying two equations with fourth power

Tags: abstract-algebra, exponentiation

Can the following two equations be satisfied simulateously for $g,r>0$?

$$g^4r\left(5g-4\right)\geq\ln\left(2\right)\ $$

$$g^3r\left(4g-3\right)\leq\ln\left(1.25\right)$$

---

From eq.2, $$g^3r \leq \frac{ln(1.25)}{4g-3}$$

Then, $$g\big(\frac{ln(1.25)}{4g-3}\big)\left(5g-4\right)>\ln\left(2\right)\ $$

$$\iff \frac{g(5g-4)}{4g-3}>\frac{ln(2)}{ln(1.5)}$$

But not sure how to find values for $g$ and $r$. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, numerically, if we take $g=3$, $r=0.000777943$  then the top left hand becomes $=\ln 2$ and the bottom left hand is $0.18904014$ which is certainly less than $\ln 1.25$

Comment: There is, of course, a whole range of solutions, I just wrote one out.  $g=2$ is too small, but it looks $g≥3$ works easily.  I didn't try to pin the solution space down.

Comment: all the solutions have $0.4 < g < 0.75$ , for this regime, $4g-3<0$ so you need to reverse the inequality from equation 2

Comment: Assume $g > 4/5$, divide the first inequality by second and simplify, you will get an inequality involving $g$. When you solve it, you will find the two inequalities have solutions when $g \ge g_0 \stackrel{def}{=}\frac{\sqrt{4K^2-7K+4}+2(K+2)}{5K}$  where $K = \log_2(5/4)$. When $g = g_0
\approx 2.555793470013948$, there is a unique $r_0 \approx 0.00185045702046613$ where the two inequalities are satisfied (in fact become an equality).